# How to join several mp4 files with multiple audio streams?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have several (2+) mp4 files. Each of them has multiple audio streams (different languages). I want to join them all in one single MP4 file and to keep all audio streams. How can I do this? Which program should I use? FFmpeg comes to my mind, but I have no experience with command line programs...

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/9155551).

Comment: You want to overlay them? Or have like a "language" choice in a video or application?

Comment: Like a language choice - the same thing as in DVD/Bluray movies - for example, one track/stream English, second French, third Spanish, etc...

Comment: Provide the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3`